# Making LCP from Suffix Array

Tags: algorithm, suffix-array

I am learning about Suffix arrays and Successful learnt how to make a Suffix array in O(nlognlogn) times From this [Tutorial](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/suffix-array-set-2-a-nlognlogn-algorithm/).

Now i am wondering How would i create LCP Array from my Suffix Array in O(nlogn) time or better obviously i know the O(n*n) approach. I want something Better

I could not find any good online resource
Please Help me so i could completely learn this topic and it will helps the other.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The simplest O(n) approach is to loop from left to right (longest to shortest) suffix. Then note that if the longest common prefix (LCP) between the current suffix at i and its neighbor in the sorted suffix array table is h, the next LCP at i + 1 can decrease by at most one. This is because the next suffix is equivalent to advancing the first character by one, so we could achieve h - 1 at least just by advancing the neighbor by one character as well. If a different suffix happens to fall in between, it will still share a prefix of at least h - 1.

This allows us to make an O(n) amortized algorithm by advancing forward as far as necessary, and then advancing back by one when moving on to the next index.

Correct (afaik) implementation: https://sites.google.com/site/indy256/algo/suffix_array

Comment: Lovely description.  It's helpful for me to think of the time complexity like this: Initially suppose we *never* decreased the LCP; then obviously over the course of the entire algorithm, it could advance at most n times (since no pair of strings can have LCP > n), for O(n) complexity overall.  But in fact we might have to decrease it by 1 for each suffix, i.e. as many as n times, and each of these decreases means one extra increase is possible later.  But then there are still at most n+n = 2n increases and n decreases, for O(3n) = O(n) steps overall.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstood what you are saying, and I haven't looked at your code, but you seem to imply that the difference between two adjacent entries of the LCP is never greater than 1. That's certainly incorrect.

Comment: Sorry for the awkward phrasing (English is not as clear as C++), but it's not as simple as you describe. We are iterating over the pre-sorting (longest to shortest) suffixes, and checking their LCPs. As you iterate over these indices (which are likely non-consecutive in the suffix array table), the LCP can only decrease by at most one.
The code in the link is quite short/clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can make LCP array from suffix array in O(n) time using kasai's alorithm

[construction of lcp array from suffix array](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kasais-algorithm-for-construction-of-lcp-array-from-suffix-array/)